# Does the Samsung Galaxy S II come with an unlocked bootloader?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, bootloader, bootloader-lock

Does the [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxys2/html/) come with an unlocked bootloader as earlier promised by Samsung?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XDA has reported](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1046748) that the bootloader is unlocked, and custom kernels [have successfully been flashed](http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/4591-Galaxy-S-II-Boot-loader-is-NOT-locked-%29-) to the SGSII.